# bash - echo: write error: invalid argument

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, echo, sh

I am new to bash and trying to write a script that disables kworker business as in aMaia's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305008/ubuntu-kworker-thread-consumes-100-cpu).

So far, I have this, which I run from root:

```
  1 #!/bin/bash                                                                      
  2                                                                                  
  3 cd /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts                                                 
  4 for i in gpe[[:digit:]]* # Don't mess with gpe_all                               
  5 do                                                                               
  6     num=`awk '{print $1}' $i`                                                    
  7     if (( $num >= 1000 )); then  # potential CPU hogs?                           
  8         # Back it up and then disable it!!                                       
  9         cp $i /root/${i}.backup                                                  
 10         echo "disable" > $i                                                      
 11     fi                                                                           
 12 done
```

But running it results in:

```
./kkiller: line 10: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

What is going on here? I thought `$i` was just the file name, which seems like the correct syntax for echo.

Suggestions for cleaning up/improving the script in general are also appreciated!

Update: With `set -vx` added to the top of the script, here is a problematic iteration:

```
+ for i in 'gpe[[:digit:]]*'
awk '{print $1}' $i
++ awk '{print $1}' gpe66
+ num=1024908
+ ((  1024908 >= 1000  ))
+ cp gpe66 /root/gpe66.backup
+ echo disable
./kkiller: line 10: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

Comment: you need to see what value is being stored in `$i`, add `set -vx` after the first line of your script. You'll get the shell debug/trace output. I think you'll see that `$i` will be value like `gpe99`, which won't work in your test `(( $num > = 1000 ))`. I'm not sure about `echo "disable" > $i`, so include more debugging output in your question so we can help you. (Cmd executed, and error msg as they occur in your output). Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has something to with permissions. I don't think root has write access to those files by default. Try echoing manually 'disable' to that file, even as root you get the same error shown.  So to make your script work, first do chmod 744 on $i before your echo, it should do the trick.

Comment: Hmm...that still gives the same error. I had been doing it manually before with no problem, so this is definitely strange!

Comment: If you can do `echo disable > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe66` then the problem is somewhere else. But I just tried it on my system and it seems to be working.

Comment: It might be a permissions thing after all, because (maybe I should've clarified in the question), by 'running it from root' I meant doing `sudo -i` and then the script, which led to the error.

If, instead, I do `sudo ./kkiller`, it works like a charm. (?!)

Comment: That astonishes me, by my knowledge there is no difference, since in both cases the program will execute under user root.

Comment: At leas on Kubuntu 23.10, the only issue was the spelling having 'ed' on the end. You have to use `disable` not `disabled`. Also though, check out using `mask` as an alternative.

Answer (score 11):

I had this problem too in Docker on Alpine linux environment. I think the problem is that echo by default put a newline character at the end of the string, and the kernel not accept it, but it is not the case in every system. In Docker I had this error, but the value was written despite the error message.

The solution (in Bash): `echo -n disable >/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe66`. This way no newline is echoed.

Comment: It works for me without `-n` just changing the argument to `disable` instead of `disabled`. Although from what other posts have said the effect of `disable` is less durable than using `mask`. Also make sure it's not `masked`, as before.

Comment: @Chris Yes it works most of the time without it, but on some distros not. I  don't know if it is because the kernel or the shell, but without the `-n` it won't work sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

Double-check all spelling. echo "disabled" will emit a write error even for root whereas echo "disable" succeeds.

Comment: Yes!! this worked! Kubuntu 17.10 on some kind of MacBook Pro.

Comment: Same result on Kubuntu 23.10. `mask|disable != masked|disabled`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message trying to disable a GPE that was already set to disabled:

```
# echo "disable" > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe17
-su: echo: write error: Invalid argument
# cat /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe17
 3718289     STS disabled     unmasked
```

After enabling it, I could disable it without an error:

```
# echo "enable" > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe17
# echo "disable" > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe17
#
```